# Two way data binding - ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

In the below angular2 component,

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  homeTitle = "Welcome to the home page";
  myString = "I like red";
  myBoolean = false;

  alertMe(val){
    alert(val);
  }

  obj = {
    name: "Yoshi",
    belt: "Black"
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

two way data binding does not work for below view,

```
<p>
  {{homeTitle}}
</p>

<!--  Property binding -->

<!-- input value="Hai" -->
<input [value]="myString">
<input [required]="myBoolean">

<button (click)="alertMe('I like x')">Click me</button>

<hr>
<!-- All above elements are working fine -->

<!-- 2 way data binding -->
<input [(ngModel)]="obj.name">
<p>{{obj.name}}</p>
<p>{{obj.belt}}</p>
```

---

Why `obj.name` does not render in the input element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Module just add `FormsModule`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
imports: [
  ..
  FormsModule
]
```

Comment: Am not sure, what module is? I just wrote one component. In the complete source tree I see `app.module.ts`.

Comment: the module in which you declared your component , since you wrote one component , so it's `AppModule`

Comment: Why `Formsmodule` is required for two way data binding? Why angular does not add this module automatically?  One way data binding is working fine without this module

Comment: `FormsModule` is required because it provides additional directives on form's elements ... , it worked ?

Comment: `ngModel` directive belongs to `FormsModule`, that's why you should import it. Thereafter you can use `ngModel` directive inside on your page. you can check the documentation for more information : https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: Why angular does not import on it's own, when parsing `ngModel` directive? Adding imports manually is not a good component based architecture. If I create component, angular automatically imported it in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: it think it's a kind of optimization , you import what you need , because you can create an application without using `FormsModule` , so it will be useless , and since there two types of Forms modules.. `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`.. so you import modules according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i saw it now.. you have to specify `name="myModelName"` in input:

like `<input name="myModelName" [(ngModel)]="obj.name">`

Comment: With name attribute it did not work. Why should it work? `name` is just an html native attribute

Comment: from angular DOCS: `When using the ngModel within <form> tags, you'll also need to supply a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent form under that name.` Do you have it inside a <form>?

Comment: can you paste your imports {} in .ts file?--- as @Mohamed Ali RACHID said, verify your imports in ts file